# Linux use "watch" with tqdm for log monitor

Tags: linux, shell, watch, tqdm

It is a normal output:

```
$grep -E '.*status' api_logging.log | tqdm --total=808 --desc='TOTAL'|wc -l

TOTAL: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 808/808 [00:00<00:00, 529365.45it/s]
808
```

But I want to keep monitoring so:
How to hide the first line of output?

```
$watch -n 1 grep -E '.*status' api_logging.log | tqdm --total=808 --desc='TOTAL'|wc -l

TOTAL:   0%|                                    | 0/808 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
TOTAL: 100%|████████████████████████████████████| 808/808 [00:00<00:00, 327466.81it/s]
```